# Android App: Adding Mailto to Web View for email functionality

Tags: android, mailto

```
package com.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.content.Context;


public class HelloWorld extends Activity
{
    final Activity activity = this;


    WebView webview;
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (webview != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.blahblah.org");

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String       description, String failingUrl)
            {
            // Handle the error
            }

     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
                MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
                Intent i = newEmailIntent(activity.this, mt.getTo(), mt.getSubject(), mt.getBody(), mt.getCc());
                startActivity(i);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            }

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
}
    public static Intent newEmailIntent(Context context, String address, String subject, String body, String cc) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { address });
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        return intent;
}
```

}

After help from people and posts on this site I was able to get a functioning web app that works.  I just need to get the "mailto" functioning and I'm good.  I have tried different code from posts I found.  The above code is getting "IntentSupport cannot be resolved" and "MIME Type cannot be resolved" Just started trying to learn this stuff.  Any feedback would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the IntentSupport class? I don't see you importing it any where. I have a feeling like it's some third party library that you don't have installed.

Comment: Your correct.  I was using the wrong bit of code that I found.  I edited it.  The code runs.  When I click a link with a mailto tag in it the devices messenger pulls up but information is not in the correct fields.  The body is entered in the "To:" field and subject and body are left blank. Can you see anything that would cause that?

Comment: Hmmmmm, I can't see anything that would cause the fields to be messed up from here. Maybe you should open a new question for that so new people can see it.